# Set values from one dictionary containing paths to another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an external main dictionary where I store some values, and a secondary dictionary which I use to iterate with **only some** names and the values I define of the first dictionary, looking something like this:

```
main_dict = {
    'colors': {
        'foo': 'orange',
        'bar': 'blue',
    },
    'fruits': {
        'xyz': 'apple',
        'abc': 'orange',
        'qwe': 'strawberry'

    }
}

secondary_dict = {
    'word1': main_dict['colors']['bar'],
    'word2': main_dict['fruits']['abc'],
    'word3': main_dict['colors']['foo']

}

#A function that iterates the keys from secondary_dict, does something, and outputs a new dictionary:
new_dict = my_function(secondary_dict)
```

And when I'm done creating that new dictionary I want to write **BACK** to the paths of original dictionary used as values in the secondary dictionary, but I'm not sure how to do so, so in a sense it would be **kind of** like doing this:

```
secondary_dict = {
    'word1': main_dict['colors']['bar'],
    'word2': main_dict['fruits']['abc'],
    'word3': main_dict['colors']['foo']

}
```

To this:

```
main_dict['colors']['bar'] = new_dict['word1'],
main_dict['fruits']['abc'] = new_dict['word2'],
main_dict['colors']['foo'] = new_dict['word3']
```

Or in (incorrect) pseudo code:

```
for key, path in secondary_dict.items():
  path = new_dict[key]
```

One of my first ideas was to instead of directly storing the paths in the secondary_dict storing them **as strings**, flipping the dictionary and iterate using **`eval()`**. But from what I can gather using `eval()` is heavily discouraged as there is always "a better way"...

**So, is there any way to do what I am trying to do without using `eval()`?**

(Apologies if it is hard to understand what I'm trying to say, I realize that it is a rather specific problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using the `collections` module.

It has two parts: A Dict_Tree class that 'flattens' access to a nested dict. (Seems to be quite similar to what @Eugene K is proposing.)

And a Proxy_Dict class. This stores the mapping from simple keys (like 'word1') to full keys (like ('colors', 'bar')), records what you are assigning to the simple keys and writes it back to the master dict either on the fly or only upon request.

```
import collections

class Dict_Tree(collections.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not data is None:
            self.data = data
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        node = self.data
        for k in key:
            node = node[k]
        return node
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        node = self.data
        for k in key[:-1]:
            node = node.setdefault(k, {})
        node[key[-1]] = value

class Proxy_Dict:
    def __init__(self, master, delayed_writeback=True, **map):
        self.delayed_writeback = delayed_writeback
        self.master = master
        if delayed_writeback:
            self.front = collections.ChainMap({}, master)
        else:
            self.front = master
        self.map = map
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.front[self.map[key]]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.front[self.map[key]] = value
    def keys(self):
        return self.map.keys()
    def values(self):
        return (self[k] for k in self.keys())
    def items(self):
        return ((k, self[k]) for k in self.keys())
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.keys())
    def writeback(self):
        if self.delayed_writeback:
            self.master.update(self.front.maps[0])

in_dict = {
    'colors': {
        'foo': 'orange',
        'bar': 'blue',
    },
    'fruits': {
        'xyz': 'apple',
        'abc': 'orange',
        'qwe': 'strawberry'

    }
}

master = Dict_Tree(in_dict)
secondary = Proxy_Dict(master,
                       word1=('colors', 'bar'),
                       word2=('fruits', 'abc'),
                       word3=('colors', 'foo'))

secondary['word1'] = 'hello'
secondary['word2'] = 'world'
secondary['word3'] = '!'

secondary.writeback()
```

Comment: Is there any way I can convert that `master` variable back to a standard dictionary? Because I am reading `in_dict` from a file and I'd like to be able to write it back to the file.

Comment: @C1N14 `master` references the data of `in_dict`. Changes to master also change `in_dict`. Just try assigning something to `master` and then look at `in_dict`.

Comment: @I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do. You mean getting from the form of `secondary` you are using in your question to my form? That would  be difficult because your form doesn't store the actual paths, right? What might be possible would be to process the source code, since it does contain the paths.

Comment: sorry, I was kind of in a rush there I don't think I even understand what I wrote lol. What I need is a way to iterate through the **already set keys** in the `Proxy_Dict`, not set them. Something like: 

`for k, v in secondary.items():` because I use the keys' names. Other than that this answer is perfect

Comment: @C1N14 I'm still not sure I understand. Are you saying you have a dictionary with keys 'word1', 'word2' etc. and you want to get its values into `in_dict['colors']['bar']` `in_dict['fruits']['abc']` etc.?

Comment: Nonono, the general structure of everything you laid down is fine. What I want to do is now that I've already set `secondary = Proxy_Dict(master,
                       word1=('colors', 'bar'),
                       word2=('fruits', 'abc'),
                       word3=('colors', 'foo'))` how do I iterate that "second" variable/object/class/whatever so when I do `for k, v in secondary.items(): print(k)` i can get as an output `word1` `word2` and `word3` like I can do with any regular old dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166174/discussion-between-c1n14-and-paul-panzer).

Answer (score 1):

If you will use path-like keys you can write a helper class, something like this:

```
from collections import reduce


class MyWrappedDict:
""" Just an example
"""
    def __init__(self, dict_source):
        self._dict_source = dict_source

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        keys = key.split('.')
        return reduce(dict.get, keys, self._dict_source)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        keys = key.split('.')
        last_key = keys[-1]
        reduce(dict.get, keys[:-1], self._dict_source)[last_key] = value
# usage
d = MyWrappedDict(main_dict)
print(d['colors.bar']) # -> 'blue'
d['colors.bar'] = 'Text'

secondary_dict = {
    'word1': 'colors.bar',
    'word2': 'fruits.abc',
    'word3': 'colors.foo'
}
```

Comment: Nice use of reduce (+1), though I think you should import it.